# Python dataclass with list

Tags: python

So just learnng Python 3.7 and I want to create a simple dataclass with two data members, an int and a list somethng like :

```
class myobject:
      data1:int
      data2:List[]

object1=myobject(1, 1)
myobject.data2.append(5)
etc...
```

I tried quite a few things but apparently the List is seen as an integer only not a list and I don't know what to do, can somebody helping me please?

cheers

Comment: "I tried quite a few things..." Show the things you tried. "but apparently..." what is your evidence for this conclusion? What happens when you tried the things you tried? Is there another conclusion that explains the behavior?

Comment: The second argument to `myobject()` should be a list, not a number. `myobject(1, [])`

Comment: If by dataclass you mean [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), then you seem to be missing actual inheritance from `dataclass`. But assuming you fix that and/or define `__init__` yourself, do you expect `1` in the second argument to be something other than an `int`?

Comment: If you assign an integer to the second field of your dataclass, then *the value is an integer*.  Type annotations are for the benefit of type-checking utilities like mypy, they do not result in any sort of runtime behavior.

Comment: And if you used mypy, it probably would have produced an error telling you that you were calling the constructor incorrectly.

Comment: Coming from C++  I was expecting to create somethng similar just looking at some google page but I failed , where can I learn such stuff in a more structured way? In the meantime if somebody could answer the question I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, the type hints are not enforced by Python. If you pass an int where you specified a list, you will get an int.

You are also creating an object of the `myobject` class, but then not using it. I think you want something like:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class myobject:
    data1: int
    data2: list

object1 = myobject(1, [1])
object1.data2.append(5)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you, can you recommend me a good book to learn Python? I think google is not enough :(

Comment: I would start by going to the source: https://www.python.org/doc/

Comment: If you feel this or other answers have helped you, SO etiquette is to upvote or accept the answer(s).